# using a regex in replacement pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a python pattern that I want to replace in two different ways.

```
Pattern: <br><b>[Ss][1-2]:[0-9]*-
1)replace by " "
2)replace s/S by Author
```

I can do the first one as it is a simple replacement, but I am not sure how can I do the second replacement as it depends upon input pattern and only a part of the expression has to be replaced.

This is working for case 1, where I just replace by blanks.

```
text="<br><b>S1:2- you are wrong. I don't think so. <br><b>S2:2- you are wrong"
newtext=re.sub("(<br><b>[Ss][1-2]:[0-9]*-)\s*", ' ',text)
print(newtext)
```

Can we have a variable expression in the replacement string?

Replaced text

```
<br><b>Author1:2- you are wrong. I don't think so. <br><b>Author2:2- you are wrong
```

Comment: can you give a sample replacement for the second use case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use look-around syntax:

```
import re
text="<br><b>S1:2- you are wrong. I don't think so. <br><b>S2:2- you are wrong"
re.sub("(?<=<br><b>)[Ss](?=[1-2]:[0-9]*-\s*)", 'Author',text)
# "<br><b>Author1:2- you are wrong. I don't think so. <br><b>Author2:2- you are wrong"
```